# Equivalent to RedirectToPage in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.0 web application with a mix of Razor Pages and MVC. When I do a POST to the page, I often want to redirect the user back to the same page, but with a GET request.

In ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages, I typically do it like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostView(...)
{
    // Update based on POST data
    ...

    return RedirectToPage();  // Redirect back to GET
}
```

What is the equivalent to this in a MVC controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent method is:

```
return RedirectToAction();
```

See the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a01e23250f98fbce016cd2b3bdf69e43fc4505c8/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L457) for more information.

Comment: Ok, only difference is that I had to pass the name of the action as a parameter like this: return RedirectToAction("Index");